# JavaScript:"onkeydown"and "onkeypress"

Tags: javascript

I want to capture the event of onkeydown to move a box but when I press the key constantly，there existing a delay，that is,when I press a key constantly,the box will move after a while.Please help me eliminate the delay.

Comment: Add your HTML and Javascript code so far. We can't help unless we know what we are dealing with.

Comment: you should provide a code or a fiddle.

Comment: explain more with posting  your attempts to avoid "VOTE-DOWN" of systemm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I believe the delay you are referring to might be the default functionality of your keyboard. For example if you open a text-editor and press and hold space you notice it will do:

> *(move over a little) (wait) (start moving)*

Keyboard events also work in this way. If you defined moving of your box to something similar to this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { 
    var key = e.which;
    if( key == 37 ) X -= speed;
    if( key == 38 ) Y -= speed;   
    if( key == 39 ) X += speed;
    if( key == 40 ) Y += speed;   
});
```

**[Here is an example of the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/g1eqbr4m/1/)**

You will notice this "type-writer" like behavior. To fix this you can use Booleans to detect when a key is pressed (`true`), then to detect when the pressed key is let go (`false`). In your screen update function check these Booleans for movement.

```
var LEFT = false , RIGHT = false, UP = false, DOWN = false;
...

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { 
    var key = e.which;
    if( key == 37 ) LEFT = true;
    if( key == 38 ) UP = true;   
    if( key == 39 ) RIGHT = true;
    if( key == 40 ) DOWN = true;   
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { 
    var key = e.which;
    if( key == 37 ) LEFT = false;
    if( key == 38 ) UP = false;     
    if( key == 39 ) RIGHT = false;
    if( key == 40 ) DOWN = false;   
});

...

// In update function

    if( LEFT ) X -= speed;
    if( UP ) Y -= speed;   
    if( RIGHT ) X += speed;
    if( DOWN ) Y += speed;
```

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/g1eqbr4m/)**

Notice in the second example the movement is much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .box {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #ccc;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
        p {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p> Press Space Bar</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log("ready");

        });

        $(document).on('keydown', function(event){

            var code = event.keyCode;

            if (code == 32) {

                var div = $('.box');

                var left = div.position().left;

                var new_left = left + 1;
                console.log(new_left);
                div.css({
                    'left': new_left + "px"
                });

            }

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

a [JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/r3rvgLyv/)

maybe this could give you a little help.
and try also to console.log on your event

Comment: Thanks for your help,but it doesn't solve my problem.Thank you.